# How do I rename a column in Dataframe SQL?

Tags: sql, deepnote

"RuntimeError: Catalog Error: Can only modify view with ALTER VIEW statement" When trying to rename a column while using DataFrame SQL within Deepnote

```
ALTER TABLE df RENAME COLUMN V41690973 TO cpi;
```

A screenshot giving some more context
[image]

Comment: seems this is a `view` not a `table`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `SELECT * EXCLUDE (col_name)` syntax in combination with Deepnote's ability to overwrite the variable `df` from Dataframe SQL to rename a column like this:

```
SELECT
    col1 as col1_renamed,
    * EXCLUDE (col1)
FROM df
```

[image]

Here's a published reproducible notebook: https://deepnote.com/@the21st/Rename-a-column-using-DataFrame-SQL-1864ef27-a977-4039-bdc5-3b81215a2f2e in case you want to fork it and try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

By following way we can Rename Column name in **MSSQL**

```
EXEC sp_rename 'TableName.FromColumnaname', 'Tocolumn';
```

To change table name

```
EXEC sp_rename 'FromTableName', 'ToTableName';
```

**Make sure that have you using anywhere in SP's or Functions it may effect functionality**