# Reusing a SQL query in deepnote

Tags: python, sql, deepnote

I am working in deepnote, and since I cannot alter my table ([How do I rename a column in Dataframe SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72796486/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-dataframe-sql)) I wondered if there is a possibility to reuse a query in a new SQL block.
I know that every query can be saved as pandas DataFrame, and with the syntax `{{ variable_name }}` variables can be reintroduced into DataFrame SQL.
However, after saving a previous SQL query as `df` the code

```
SELECT *
FROM {{ df }}
```

does unfortunately not work.

The error message I get is: `"There is no Dataframe named ? in scope!"`
What am I missing here?

FYI: Deepnote's DataFrame SQL is based on  [JinjaSQL](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/jinjasql), if that helps in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deepnote allows you to reference dataframe variables directly as table names in SQL. So you should be able to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM df
```

instead of using the JinjaSQL syntax.

Example: https://deepnote.com/@the21st/Querying-dataframes-with-SQL-4ac53104-9b0e-4f7b-897c-2ddbe0923d34